# Get texts of Organogram SmartArt in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would to get the texts of an Smart Art organogram to vba.

Like, in the following photo, I would like to get "Text", "Text1", "Text2" and "Text3" and know how they're positioned in the hierarchy.

[image: Organogram with four boxes containing the texts mentioned previously in this question]

I couldn't find anything related on the internet.
Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?
Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [SmartArt.AllNodes property (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.smartart.allnodes?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Shape.HasSmartArt property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.hassmartart?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm547085)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub GetOrganogramText()
    Dim shapeIndex As Long
    Dim objSArt As SmartArt
    Dim objNode As SmartArtNode
    With ActiveSheet
        For shapeIndex = 1 To .Shapes.Count
            If .Shapes(shapeIndex).HasSmartArt Then
                Set objSArt = .Shapes(shapeIndex).SmartArt
                If objSArt.Layout.Category = "hierarchy" Then
                    For Each objNode In objSArt.AllNodes
                        Debug.Print "Level: " & objNode.Level & vbTab & "Text: " _
                                & objNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
                    Next objNode
                End If
            End If
        Next shapeIndex
    End With
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Level: 1    Text: A1
Level: 2    Text: AA2
Level: 3    Text: DD3
Level: 2    Text: BB2
Level: 2    Text: CC2
Level: 3    Text: EE3
Level: 4    Text: FF4
```

---

Update:

> Question: How can I know which is father of DD3? "AA2", "CC2" or "BB2"

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub GetParentNode()
    Dim shapeIndex As Integer
    Dim objSArt As SmartArt
    Dim objNode As SmartArtNode
    Const TARGET_NODE = "DD3"
    With ActiveSheet
        For shapeIndex = 1 To .Shapes.Count
            If .Shapes(shapeIndex).HasSmartArt Then
                Set objSArt = .Shapes(shapeIndex).SmartArt
                If objSArt.Layout.Category = "hierarchy" Then
                    For Each objNode In objSArt.AllNodes
                        If objNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = TARGET_NODE Then
                            Debug.Print "Parent node is " _
                                & objNode.ParentNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
                        End If
                    Next objNode
                End If
            End If
        Next shapeIndex
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How can I know which is father of DD3? "AA2", "CC2" or "BB2"

Comment: I've uploaded a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

To display in the Immediate Window the text from the first node in the diagram, try...

```
Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Diagram 1").SmartArt.AllNodes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
```

To display in the immediate Window the text for each of the nodes in the diagram, try...

```
Dim nodeIndex As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Diagram 1").SmartArt.AllNodes
    For nodeIndex = 1 To .Count
        Debug.Print .Item(nodeIndex).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
    Next nodeIndex
End With
```

Change the sheet name and diagram name accordingly.